# Tensorflow Linear Regression Not Converging to Correct Values

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I have a csv data set with 2 columns, an input and output column and when I use Excel to to find the trend line, I get:

y = -0.4571x + 0.9011

When I run the following code w and converge to different values depending on the learning rate and batch size I choose. I have played around with different values without any luck. Maybe I am missing something perhaps?

The cost doesn't seem to change either.

```
learningRate = 0.001
epochs = 2000
batchSize = 20

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Brian\\Desktop\\data.csv")
X = df[df.columns[0]].values
Y = df[df.columns[1]].values

def getBatch(batchSize, inputs, outputs):
    idx = np.arange(0,len(inputs))
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
    idx = idx[:batchSize]
    xBatch = [inputs[i] for i in idx]
    yBatch = [outputs[i] for i in idx]
    xBatch = np.reshape(xBatch, (batchSize,1))
    return np.asarray(xBatch), np.asarray(yBatch)

w = tf.Variable(0.0, tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(0.0, tf.float32)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)

prediction = tf.add(tf.multiply(x,w), b)

cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(prediction-y))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        xBatch, yBatch = getBatch(batchSize,X,Y)
        #for (trainX, trainY) in zip(xBatch,yBatch):
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: xBatch, y: yBatch})

        if(epoch+1) % 50 == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: X, y: Y})
            print("Epoch:", (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.4f}".format(c), "w=", sess.run(w), "b=", sess.run(b))

    print("Optimization Finished")
    trainingCost = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: X, y:Y})
    print("Training cost=", trainingCost, "w=", sess.run(w), "b=", sess.run(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the following code w and converge to different values depending on the learning rate and batch size I choose.

Because, if you run `sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: xBatch, y: yBatch})` TensorFlow does something like below.

`w -= learningRate * dw`

where `dw` is the value calculated by gradient descent optimizer.

So if you change `learningRate` and then run the program, you get different value of `w`. And `w` affect `dw` and `dw` affect next `w`. So it's difficult to predict what value `w` will become if you change the `learningRate`.